# ubuntu 10.04 alternate has no GUI

Tags: 10.04, gui, alternate

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04.4-alternate as I would like to have the feature of encryption LVM. But after installation, the system boot into text mode, like Ubuntu server but not Ubuntu desktop. Is it so that alternate version doesn't provide GUI feature??

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. You have to install the GUI with:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

after logging in.

If you like you can have more desktops like kubuntu,Lubuntu,Xubuntu also.

all you need to do is just replace ubuntu with kubuntu in the above command and so to get those GUI's.

Comment: You are asked during installation what packages to install.  If you want the gnome desktop, you have to select it.

Comment: @Frantique: hi, the ubuntu-desktop is already installed (when boot and shutdown you can see it), but after the system is booted, the desktop doesn't show up, only command line is available...

Comment: @psusi: no, i was not asked which package to install. But as i said, it is already installed but doesn't show. :(

Comment: @vivienlwt: try to start X manually with `startx` command, perhaps there is some error on loading.

Comment: yes, indeed there's an error: "Fatal server error: AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0". I guess that the OS doesn't have the right driver for the monitor. It is NEC LCD 2070WNX, but the website only have driver for Windows...

Comment: This kind of problem typically occurs when you're using a big monitor with an old graphics card. Try this before starting Xorg: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but still got the same error. It also mentioned that "xinit: No such file or directory(errno 2): unabl to connect to X server, xinit: No such process (errno 3): server error." The VGA controller is Intel Corporation Device 0152.